# Чем можно заменить данную строку?

Tags: c++

Чем можно заменить данную строчку: `std::copy(b, i, std::ostream_iterator<char>(cout, ""));`

вот использование этой строки:  `if (st == 5 || (st == 4 && *i == '\0')) std::copy(b, i, std::ostream_iterator<char>(cout, ""));`

Comment: `for (auto iter = b; iter != i; ++iter) cout << *iter;`

Comment: а что значит auto iter и сам iter?

Comment: `auto iter` - создание переменной с именем `iter` и типом там же как и `b`. Если б я знал что такое `b` и `i`, то можно было б и без `auto` обойтись.